# Syntax for using regex in ruby / watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

I am able to find an element I'm looking for using an exact match on the text, as shown below, but when I try to extend this to using a regex it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
>> browser.h3(:text => 'Latest News').exist?
=> true
>> browser.h3(:text, 'Latest News').exist?
=> true
>> browser.h3(:text, /Latest News/).exist?
=> false
```

---

```
>> p browser.h3(:text, 'Latest News')
#<Watir::Heading:0x..fcb7790992119c2b2 located=false selector={:text=>"Latest News", :tag_name=>"h3"}>
=> #<Watir::Heading:0x..fcb7790992119c2b2 located=false selector={:text=>"Latest News", :tag_name=>"h3"}>
>> p browser.h3(:text, /Latest News/)
#<Watir::Heading:0x54fac9ec99992782 located=false selector={:text=>/Latest News/, :tag_name=>"h3"}>
=> #<Watir::Heading:0x54fac9ec99992782 located=false selector={:text=>/Latest News/, :tag_name=>"h3"}>
```

**EDIT**  based on comments, found following HTML that seems to be what he's after, on the afl site.  This is the only match in the page html for a case insensitive search for "latest news'

```
<div class="double-col column">
  <div class="segment   ">
    <h3 class="section-header    blocked">
        LATEST NEWS</h3>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="list-item focus">
        <div class="img-holder">
      .........
```

Comment: Can you give us the full sentences on which `regex` is being applied?

Comment: Can you do `p browser.h3(:text, 'Latest News')` and `p browser.h3(:text, /Latest News/)` ? and show us the result

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML, or better yet link to the relevant page.

Comment: @wim what I asked, can you give? Hope that would help.

Comment: @RubyLovely Haven't I already?

Comment: can you now do `p browser.h3(:text, 'Latest News').class` and `p browser.h3(:text, /Latest News/).class`? Actually where I am now sitting don't have watir gem installed? Thus need your help.

Comment: went to site, found closest html I could and added to the question, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your results given the test site. For me, all of the locators using 'Latest News' return false (ie both string and regex matches). The page text is in all caps, 'LATEST NEWS'. Using that instead of 'Latest News' allowed both the string and regex locators to return true.

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto 'afl.com.au'

puts browser.h3(:text => 'Latest News').exist?
#=> false
puts browser.h3(:text, 'Latest News').exist?
#=> false
puts browser.h3(:text, /Latest News/).exist?
#=> false

puts browser.h3(:text => 'LATEST NEWS').exist?
#=> true
puts browser.h3(:text, 'LATEST NEWS').exist?
#=> true
puts browser.h3(:text, /LATEST NEWS/).exist?
#=> true
```

Comment: Strange.  I updated my ruby versions and gems, and now the misbehaviour magically disappeared I have the same result as you.

Comment: Note: using regex can sometimes be a bit slow, so generally it is best to avoid it unless it is needed